# regular functions on open sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

This is a proof given in Gathmann's AG lecture notes for the regular functions on $U=A^2-\{(0,0)\}$.

Denote $D_f$ as the distinguished open set of function $f$.

It is clear that any regular function on $U$ has two representations as either $\frac{f_1}{x_1^n}$ or $\frac{f_2}{x_2^m}$. And two representation agrees on $D_{x_1}\cap D_{x_2}$. Then he concludes that $D_{x_1}\cap D_{x_2}\subset V(f_1x_2^m-f_2x_1^n)$ where the latter is closed and thus $Cl(D_{x_1}\cap D_{x_2})=A^2$. I do not see the last step.

My guess is that $A^2$ is irreducible. So denote $Cl(A)$ as closure of a set $A$. $Cl(D_{x_1}\cap D_{x_2}))\cup V(x_1x_2)=A^2$. So the closure must contain $A^2$ as $A^2$ is irreducible. Am I right on this part?

The other question is showing that if $U=X-V$ where $V$ is an irreducible codimension 2 subvariety of $X$, then $O_X(V)=A(X)$ where $A(X)$ is the coordinate ring of variety $X$. Why irreducible codimension 2 is required here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your guess is correct. Since $\mathbb{A}^2$ is irreducible, any open set is dense for the reasons you mention.

The reason that codimension 2 is required is that the statement is false in codimension 1: take $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus{0}$, which has $k[x^{\pm1}]$ as it's regular functions.

Comment: Do you have any intuition on codimension 2 case? I cannot see geometric picture for the second question or I do not know how to visualize the geometric picture of this.

Comment: @user45765 The intuition is that if one has more functions on $U$ then they'd look like quotients $\frac{f}{g}$ for functions on $X$ with $g$ having zeros only on $V$, right? But, this says that $V(g)\subseteq V$, but $V(g)$ has codimension $1$ and so can't be contained inside of codimension $2$. In short: the poles of a meromorphic function are at least a codimension $1$ set.

Comment: My intuition about this is that any individual algebraic/holomorphic function can only see things of codimension 1- past that, the stuff gets 'too small' for them to pick out. I guess there's also a vague analogy with excision here too, but I'm less sure about a slogan here.